# Shifting a div to the left on click in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am trying to allow the user to shift a div to the left or right in angularjs. Right now I have the function below. It works on the first click but all it does is toggle every click and is saying `left` is `NaN`. What am I doing wrong here? Also if someone has a better solution for this please let me know.

```
vm.scrollSelector = function(e, direction) {
    var target = document.getElementById('item-selector');
    var left = target.style.left;

    if(direction === 'left') {
      left += 600;
      target.setAttribute('style', 'left: ' + left + 'px');
    } else {
      left -= 600;
      target.setAttribute('style', 'left: ' + left + 'px');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I quickly found the answer just by looking at the docs. Left is returned as a string so all I had to to was do `parseInt(left) + 600` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`vm.scrollSelector = function(e, direction) {
        var target = document.getElementById('item-selector');
        var left = target.style.left.match(/\d+/);
        left = parseInt(left[0], 10)
        if(direction === 'left') {
          left += 600;
          target.setAttribute('style', 'left: ' + left + 'px');
        } else {
          left -= 600;
          target.setAttribute('style', 'left: ' + left + 'px');
        }
    }`

First try to see what value target.style.left is returning. It might be returning value like '10px'. You need to convert this into a number first then perform the addition or subtraction.